# openshift webhook github response "code":500

Tags: github, openshift, webhooks, redhat-openjdk

I set up a webhook from my github repository to openshift and it was able to successfully send a request once. The second and the following request(s) after a push to the repository, however, resulted in the following error response:

```
{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Internal error occurred: could not generate a build: Error resolving ImageStreamTag redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image","reason":"InternalError","details":{"causes":[{"message":"could not generate a build: Error resolving ImageStreamTag redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image"}]},"code":500}
```

How can it be that the previously existing default image template redhat-openjdk18-openshift can not be found?
What can I do about it?

Edit: I have been asked to perform:

```
$oc get is -n openshift
```

this is the result of it:

```
NAME                                  DOCKER REPO                                                                  TAGS                              UPDATED
dotnet                                172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/dotnet                                          latest,1.1,1.0                    3 weeks ago
jboss-webserver30-tomcat7-openshift   registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat7-openshift   latest,1.3,1.3-13 + 2 more...     3 weeks ago
jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift   registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-webserver-3/webserver30-tomcat8-openshift   1.3,1.3-12,1.3-11 + 2 more...     3 weeks ago
jenkins                               172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/jenkins                                         1,2,latest                        3 weeks ago
mariadb                               172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/mariadb                                         latest,10.1                       3 weeks ago
mongodb                               172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/mongodb                                         3.2,2.6,2.4 + 1 more...           3 weeks ago
mysql                                 172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/mysql                                           latest,5.7,5.6 + 1 more...        3 weeks ago
nodejs                                172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/nodejs                                          0.10,4,6 + 1 more...              3 weeks ago
perl                                  172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/perl                                            5.24,5.20,5.16 + 1 more...        3 weeks ago
php                                   172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/php                                             latest,7.0,5.6 + 1 more...        3 weeks ago
postgresql                            172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/postgresql                                      latest,9.5,9.4 + 1 more...        3 weeks ago
python                                172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/python                                          latest,3.5,3.4 + 2 more...        3 weeks ago
redhat-openjdk18-openshift            registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift             1.1-11,1.1-10,1.1-8 + 2 more...   3 weeks ago
redis                                 172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/redis                                           latest,3.2                        3 weeks ago
ruby                                  172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/ruby                                            latest,2.3,2.2 + 1 more...        3 weeks ago
wildfly                               172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/wildfly                                         latest,10.1,10.0 + 2 more...      3 weeks ago
```

beside this, I noticed the following:

> The ImageStreamTag "redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0" is invalid: from: Error resolving ImageStreamTag redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image

```
$oc status -v
In project budgetting on server https://api.starter-us-west-1.openshift.com:443

http://budgetting-budgetting.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com (svc/budgetting)
  dc/budgetting deploys openshift/jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift:1.3-12 
    deployment #3 deployed 4 hours ago - 1 pod
    deployment #2 failed 4 hours ago: newer deployment was found running
    deployment #1 deployed 29 hours ago

bc/budgetting source builds https://github.com/Macilias/Budgetting.git#master on openshift/redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0
  -> istag/budgetting:latest
  not built yet

Warnings:
  * istag/budgetting:latest needs to be imported or created by a build.
    try: oc start-build budgetting

Info:
  * dc/budgetting has no readiness probe to verify pods are ready to accept traffic or ensure deployment is successful.
    try: oc set probe dc/budgetting --readiness ...
  * dc/budgetting has no liveness probe to verify pods are still running.
    try: oc set probe dc/budgetting --liveness ...

View details with 'oc describe <resource>/<name>' or list everything with 'oc get all'.

mniemczyk@Macieks-MBP: ~/Programming/
$oc start-build budgetting
The ImageStreamTag "redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0" is invalid: from: Error resolving ImageStreamTag redhat-openjdk18-openshift:1.0 in namespace openshift: unable to find latest tagged image
```

So should I fix this? Where is this ImageStreamTag? Its not in my WS!

Edit 2: I was asked to perform: oc describe is/redhat-openjdk18-openshift -n openshift
Thats the result:

```
    $oc describe is/redhat-openjdk18-openshift -n openshift
Name:           redhat-openjdk18-openshift
Namespace:      openshift
Created:        3 weeks ago
Labels:         <none>
Annotations:        openshift.io/image.dockerRepositoryCheck=2017-08-09T21:50:02Z
Docker Pull Spec:   172.30.148.65:5000/openshift/redhat-openjdk18-openshift
Image Lookup:       local=false
Unique Images:      5
Tags:           6

latest
  tagged from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift:latest

  * registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:6cc8c860c58536bdf29e61ad8518b77e820486f9daa9d01a4f2a893d549489d7
      3 weeks ago

1.1
  tagged from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift:1.1

  * registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:94447614d04b496c342e3447a4fd72f0f0743feaee9089e50e018514b53515ff
      3 weeks ago

1.1-11
  tagged from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift:1.1-11

  * registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:70c9fd7db73eee95f564f8221ef58eb59cf34f66bb5d98cb0a4dfabc18075e93
      3 weeks ago

1.1-10
  tagged from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift:1.1-10

  * registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:314fd4e661387f33534517b293a8ec4d4f55186ec283ae2b94ab4b86d0729c5d
      3 weeks ago

1.1-8
  tagged from registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift:1.1-8

  * registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-openjdk-18/openjdk18-openshift@sha256:60670a75b867b2a65f8c2f526ff3ab9d0d8cf2fa39b352928d7014b50d54ff34
      3 weeks ago

1.0
  pushed image

  Build and run Java applications using Maven and OpenJDK 8.
  Tags: builder, java, xpaas, openjdk
  Supports: java:8, xpaas:1.0
  Example Repo: https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-quickstarts
```

Comment: Run ``oc get is -n openshift``. This will show what images are setup in the ``openshift`` namespace and available to any project in the cluster.

Comment: I executed the command and added the output here, but I don't see how it can help. In fact, it didn't until now...

Comment: So it exists. Now run ``oc describe is/redhat-openjdk18-openshift -n openshift``. Is there a 1.0 tag on the image stream?

Comment: as you can see - 1.0 is not part of the list, but how comes it´s requested, I did check the code and the configuration multiple times now, it's never declared or requested as such.

Comment: i give up - switching to Heroku - everything worked right out of the box!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with how the redhat-openjdk18-openshift imagestream is defined in the cluster.  We are working to correct this, it is not currently importing the correct set of tags and as a result the 1.0 tag was stopped being a valid tag, incorrectly.

However the short term solution would have been to change your buildconfig to reference one of the tags that has a valid image reference associated (e.g. 1.1) instead of the 1.0 tag it is currently referencing.

Sorry you had a bad experience, hopefully you'll give OpenShift another try in the future.

Comment: A bit earlier and this answer would have saved my weekend.

Comment: @Ben Why haven't you changed the default on the web console?

Comment: It's not under my control but the tag corrections are being rolled out, hopefully today.

Comment: @Ben great to hear.  I really struggled with this.  Still working to get my java app up on V3